# SQL MATCH()AGAINST() Not working for 4Z match

Tags: sql

I want to match (filter) data from mysql with `MATCH() AGAINST()`and tried to filter data.

```
SELECT * FROM ts_mail_emails_1 AS bem WHERE MATCH(subject) AGAINST ('+"ticket" +"time" +"limit"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This is working fine to search data

```
SELECT * FROM ts_mail_emails_1 AS bem WHERE MATCH(subject) AGAINST ('+"4Z" +"ticket" +"time" +"limit"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This is not working for me.

My  subject `4Z ticket time limit` exists in the database.

When I tried with `4ZZ ticket time limit` or `64Z ticket time limit` then it works for me.

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) - providing some proper source data samples (as text please, not pictures!)) would be very helpful. A SQLFiddle demo would be even better. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. Since you're new (welcome) I'd also strongly recommend taking the [tour]. You can [edit] your post to add new info - don't bury it down in the comment section. Thankyou.

Comment: By default the minimum word length in MySQL is 4 characters. Since 4ZZ and 64Z work for you, I suspect you've decreased it to 3 characters. But 4Z is shorter than that.

Comment: Also please clarify of you use mysql or planetscale because the two are not the same, just highly compatible